# Boolean behaving strange, logic issue

Tags: ruby, if-statement, boolean

I'm having an issue with boolean expected behavior. I can make the desired result but I'm not sure why the strange behavior occurs. This produces a wrong result:

```
def palindrome?(string)
  rev = string.reverse
  if rev == string
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

palindrome?("abc") == false # => true
palindrome?("abcba") == true # => true
palindrome?("z") == true # => true
```

while this produces the correct result:

```
def palindrome?(string)
  rev = string.reverse
  if rev == string
    true
  end
end

palindrome?("abc") == false # => false
palindrome?("abcba") == true # => true
palindrome?("z") == true # => true
```

The following might be similar:

```
def nearby_az(string)
  counter = 0
  string = string.split("")
  if string.count == 1
    false
  elsif (string.index("z") - string.index("a")) <= 3
    true
  else
    false
  end
end

nearby_az("a") == false # => true
nearby_az("z") == false # => true
```

Comment: `palindrome?("abc")` returns `false`, `false == false` is `true`, what is the strange behavior????

Comment: I've tried that, but the output does not check out: `palindrome?("abc") == false: true
`

Answer (score 3):

Because Ruby method will return the result of executing the last expression. For this `if` statement:

```
if rev == string
    true
end
```

it will return `nil` if `rev != string`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your first function is producing the correct result. The problem is the second formula. It returns nothing if the string is not a palindrome; it only returns `true` if the string is a palindrome. Therefore,

```
palindrome?("abc") == false
```

for the second equation returns `false` because `palindrome?("abc")` returns nothing because `"abc"` is not a palindrome, and so it is not equal to `false`.

Comment: That "nothing" is in fact something: `nil`

Answer (score 0):

The second implementation of `palindrome?` will return `nil` if it is not a palindrome. Thus `nil == false # => false`. In Ruby, all functions return something although it may be `nil`.

Comment: Adding on to this answer: based on the content of question, you are checking for `palindrome?(string) == false`. This will return `true` if the function returns false because `false == false #=> true`. Just run `palindrome?(string)` to get the actual output.